# BeautifulSoup doesn't find, findAll, or get a div by its ID

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been on this for the last two days non-stop...
I'm trying to get a specific div by its ID using BeautifulSoup as so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('www.example.com', cookies=cookies_dict)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
div_text = soup.get('div', {'id': 'this_div_id'}).text
print div_text
```

All I get is a dictionary:

```
{'id': 'this_div_id'}
```

Now, I checked to make sure that 'this_div_id' actually is inside of r.content:

```
>>> 'this_div_id' in r.content
True
```

I'd be glad to receive any help and suggestions.

Comment: `{'id', 'this_div_id'}` is a `set`, not a `dict` (the `dict` would be `{'id': 'this_div_id'}`). This set aside, it's impossible to answer your question without the source html (or at least enough of it to reproduce the issue).

Comment: Unfortuantely I cannot add that here. The div is inside many other elements, which led me to wonder whether BeautifulSoup only goes so far inside the HTML until it stops.

Comment: "Unfortuantely I cannot add that here. The div is inside many other elements" => how does this prevent you to post a html fragment reproducing the issue exactly ???

Comment: self-correction: it _was_  actually possible to answer the question without the minimal html source... But that doesn't mean posting debugging question without a MCVE is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Err... Maybe you should check `BeautifulSoup` documentation again ?-)

> Help on method get in module bs4.element:
>
> get(self, key, default=None) unbound bs4.BeautifulSoup method
>       Returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag, or
>       the value given for 'default' if it doesn't have that
>       attribute.

I think you want the `find()` method instead:

```
>>> html = """<html><body><div><div><div id='this_div_id'>haha</div></div></div>"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> s.find("div")
<div><div><div id="this_div_id">haha</div></div></div>
>>> s.find("div", id="this_div_id")
*<div id="this_div_id">haha</div>
>>>
```